# Embedding python sample code in c++ got error for "can not find function"

Tags: python, c++

I tried embedding python in c++ from official document

https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html
5.3. Pure Embedding

I noticed a problem that the code will fail if you name the script to certain names

It's working for test1.py abcd.py but not working for abc.py test.py

```
C:\Temp
> PythonTest.exe test1 multiply 2 3
Will compute 2 times 3
Result of call: 6

C:\Temp
> PythonTest.exe abcd multiply 2 3
Will compute 2 times 3
Result of call: 6

C:\Temp
> PythonTest.exe abc multiply 2 3
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'multiply'
Cannot find function "multiply"

C:\Temp
> PythonTest.exe test multiply 2 3
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'multiply'
Cannot find function "multiply"
```

Comment: afaik `abc` and `test` are builtin modules ... and neither has multiply ... at a guess abc and test are actuall triggering builtin modules? maybe?